# javax.jms.JMSException: Channel was inactive for too long: localhost/127.0.0.1:7676

Tags: connection, jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to connect jms server using ActiveMQ from a stand alone java code but I am struggling with following exception. I tried various options but not able to figure out root cause.

It is failing at following line of code:

```
jmsConnection.start();
```

my broker url is:

```
tcp://localhost:7676?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0
```

Stack Trace is as follows:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Channel was inactive for too long: localhost/127.0.0.1:7676
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:62)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1206)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1289)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.start(ActiveMQConnection.java:456)
        at com.bt.ccdr.dbtoqueue.DBToQueueHelperImpl.getJMSConnection(DBToQueueHelperImpl.java:172)
        at com.bt.ccdr.dbtoqueue.DBToQueueHelperImpl.main(DBToQueueHelperImpl.java:42)
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Channel was inactive for too long: localhost/127.0.0.1:7676
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.oneway(InactivityMonitor.java:225)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.oneway(TransportFilter.java:83)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:100)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:40)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:74)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:79)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1195)
        ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the connection sting to `failover:(tcp://localhost:7676)`. The [failover transport](https://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html) layers reconnect logic over the standard OpenWire tcp transport.

Comment: Thanks Jake, I have changes connection string as above. After this change I am getting following logs printed,

Aug 13, 2013 6:45:47 PM org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport doReconnect
INFO: Successfully connected to tcp://localhost:7676
Aug 13, 2013 6:45:47 PM org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport handleTransportFailure
WARNING: Transport failed to tcp://localhost:7676 , attempting to automatically reconnect due to: java.io.IOException: Unknown data type: 99

Comment: This sounds like some sort of wire format mismatch. Are you using the same version of ActiveMQ client library as the broker? More to the point, are you using an ActiveMQ broker at all? 7676 is the default port used by OpenMQ, which needs the OpenMQ JMS library and not the ActiveMQ one.

Comment: Thanks Jake,
I am quite new to JMS and your hint helped me a lot. Using openMQ API i am able to connect and send messages to queue.
Thanks a lot again!!!!